# determine if set is open or closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have to determine whether the sset {1,2,3} is open or closed.
I have never done these types of questions before but this is what I did (on pic).

please can I have some feedback if I have done it correctly or not.

thanks.[image]

Comment: What is your definition of "open" and "closed"?

Comment: @MarkBennet I think its kind of borel set interval with semi open and closed?

Comment: @valerie There are definitions of closed sets which, for example, refer to limit points or adherent points.

Comment: If you know that a single point is closed, then any finite set is closed (they are finite unions of closed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in F^c$.

Define $r=\min\{d(x,1),d(x,2),d(x,3)\}$.

Then $B(x,r) \subset F^c$.